# Which CAS Server should I use?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, single-sign-on, cas

I don't know very much about CAS, except that I need Single Sign On for a few internal websites, and that this is probably my best option.

What's a good CAS Server to use in an all Ruby on Rails environment?

What's a good CAS Server to use in a mix of Ruby on Rails and Java environment?

I see rubycas.  They have a client.  Will this client work in Rails with all CAS Servers or just the rubycas server?

If I'm looking to overhaul the entire sign on system, should I add LDAP behind CAS?

Answer (score 2):

If it needs to be an all Ruby environment you will need to use rubycas-server (http://code.google.com/p/rubycas-server/) and the unofficial Ruby CAS client (https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Ruby+on+Rails+CAS+Client).

If it can be a mixed Ruby/Java environment, I'd imagine that you would want to look at using the original Java CAS server (http://www.jasig.org/cas/download) and the unofficial Ruby CAS client. The Java CAS server is really just a webapp that can be run on something like Tomcat.

Any client should work with either server according to documentation (I've tried a few for the Java "server" and all have worked fine).

The backend should not really matter to the overall architecture. If you want to use LDAP...go for it. In fact, if you want to use the original CAS Server and don't want to write much Java, there will be projects you can leverage to use LDAP whereas if you are using a homegrown solution, you will need to write that implementation.